# Making VBA Macro work on different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I'm new to SO, although I have done some searching for answers as an anonymous searcher. Unfortunately, unless I'm missing it, I couldn't find the answer to my specific issue. Some came close but not quite. So here goes.

The macro I have posted below works great in the home or native workbook. It's a very specific program that works with similar data from different sources. I'd like it to work in any workbook for which I bring up the data.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'll put it in anyway to add some detail for thought.

We pull data from different automated medication dispensing stations and then sort it in an effort to optimize the station for medication availability. So, while the data is generally similar the data row range for each sheet from each station is different. I think what is happening is the program is looking for the original range and perhaps sheet. I want to make it dynamic so I can run it in any workbook. Thanks for you help. 
Below is the code. The debugging screen highlights from

I'm assuming that is where the bug exists that is preventing it from running. The Error I'm getting is:

> Run time error '5':
>   Invalid procedure call or argument

Thanks everyone

```
Sub Days_Unused()
'
' Days_Unused Macro
' Converts Hospital Wide Report Data to Pivot Table
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Hospital_Wide_Inventory!R1C1:R671C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). 

        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MedDescription")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Device")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField 
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DaysUnused"), "Sum of 
    DaysUnused", xlSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below to set-up the `PivotTable` dynamically according to the occupied range in "Hospital_Wide_Inventory" sheet.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Days_Unused()

' Converts Hospital Wide Report Data to Pivot Table
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d

Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim HospitalSht As Worksheet

Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Dim SrcRng As Range, SrcRngString As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
' add new sheet for Pivot-Table
Set PvtSht = WB1.Sheets.Add

' set "Hospital_Wide_Inventory" worksheet object
Set HospitalSht = WB1.Worksheets("Hospital_Wide_Inventory")

With HospitalSht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

    ' set the Pivot source range object dynamicaly to the last row with data
    Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 15))

    SrcRngString = SrcRng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) ' get the address of the range, including the sheet's name
End With

' set the Pivot Cache object
Set PvtCache = WB1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRngString)

' create the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

' not set the Pivot-Fields
With PvtTbl
    With .PivotFields("MedDescription")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Device")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ' add sum field
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("DaysUnused"), "Sum of DaysUnused", xlSum
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! thank you Shai. Since I'm trying to learn VBA I typed in the code instead of cutting and pasting. It made me speak the code in my head as I was typing. In any case when I ran the code and then the debugger I got the following error

Comment: Wow! thank you Shai. Since I'm trying to learn VBA I typed in the code instead of cutting and pasting. It made me speak the code in my head as I was typing. In any case when I ran the code and then the debugger I got a compille error: Variable not defined. In With HospitalSht LastRow = .Cells(Rows etc x1Up is not defined as a variable. How should i fix it. thanks

Comment: Yes Shai I understand that. But I couldn't figure out how to properly format it in the comments box. I've typed it in to the module exactly as you have. I think

Comment: @Louis are you sure you copied my entire code as it is ? since they are all defined in my code.

Comment: You're right Shai. I copied your code into a module and it worked perfectly. So I have to find the error in the code I typed. Thank you so much for your help. I've learned a lot today

Comment: BTW, Have a great weekend